# Bibtopic + Apacite in ClassicThesis

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, classicthesis

I'm using ClassicThesis (fresh raw TeX version compiled with TexMaker and MikTex 2.9, both up-to-date in Windows).

I have managed to apply apacite style with the default bibliography commands. The only thing I had to do was commentig the `natbib` package in `classicthesis-config.tex`. And to put the `\usepackage{apacite}` after the hyperref setup.

The problem arises now that I want to handle two `bib` files. And I thought of bibtopic package. It does exactly, theoretically, what I need to do. But it's impossible for me to get it working.

This is the `classicthesis.tex` MWE:

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude, footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper, ngerman,american]{scrreprt}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblio1.bib} 
@MISC{Aronofsky1998,
  author = {Aronofsky, Darren},
  title = {{Pi, fe en el caos}},
  year = {1998},
  publisher = {Harvest Film Works Truth \& Soul / Planttain Films}
}
\end{filecontents*} 

\begin{filecontents*}{biblio2.bib} 
@TECHREPORT{APA,
  author = {APA},
  title = {{C\'{o}mo preparar una bibliograf\'{\i}a seg\'{u}n el manual de estilo
    APA, 6 ed.}},
  }
\end{filecontents*} 

%********************************************************************
% Note: Make all your adjustments in here
%*******************************************************
\input{classicthesis-config}


% ********************************************************************
% GO!GO!GO! MOVE IT!
%*******************************************************
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{american} % american ngerman
\renewcommand*{\bibname}{Biblio}
%\setbibpreamble{}


Here goes some cites: \cite{Aronofsky1998} and \cite{APA}. 





%********************************************************************
% Bibliography
%*******************************************************
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 

%\bibliography{biblio1}

\begin{btSect}{biblio1} 
\section{Biblio DB 1} 
\btPrintCited 
\end{btSect} 

\begin{btSect}{biblio2} 
\section{BiblioDB 2} 
\btPrintCited 
\end{btSect} 


\end{document}
% ********************************************************************
```

And this is the full `classicthesis-config.tex`, modified. As I said, just commented `natbib` usage and put `bibtopic` and `apacite` after `hyperref` setup.

```
% ****************************************************************************************************
% classicthesis-config.tex 
% formerly known as loadpackages.sty, classicthesis-ldpkg.sty, and classicthesis-preamble.sty 
% Use it at the beginning of your ClassicThesis.tex, or as a LaTeX Preamble 
% in your ClassicThesis.{tex,lyx} with \input{classicthesis-config}
% ****************************************************************************************************  
% If you like the classicthesis, then I would appreciate a postcard. 
% My address can be found in the file ClassicThesis.pdf. A collection 
% of the postcards I received so far is available online at 
% http://postcards.miede.de
% ****************************************************************************************************

% ****************************************************************************************************
% 1. Configure classicthesis for your needs here, e.g., remove "drafting" below 
% in order to deactivate the time-stamp on the pages
% ****************************************************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{eulerchapternumbers,listings,drafting,%
                 pdfspacing,%floatperchapter,%linedheaders,%
                 subfig,beramono,eulermath,parts}{classicthesis}                                        
% ********************************************************************
% Available options for classicthesis.sty 
% (see ClassicThesis.pdf for more information):
% drafting
% parts nochapters linedheaders
% eulerchapternumbers beramono eulermath pdfspacing minionprospacing
% tocaligned dottedtoc manychapters
% listings floatperchapter subfig
% ********************************************************************

% ********************************************************************
% Triggers for this config
% ******************************************************************** 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{enable-backrefs} % enable backrefs in the bibliography
\setboolean{enable-backrefs}{false} % true false
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 2. Personal data and user ad-hoc commands
% ****************************************************************************************************
\newcommand{\myTitle}{A Classic Thesis Style\xspace}
\newcommand{\mySubtitle}{An Homage to The Elements of Typographic Style\xspace}
\newcommand{\myDegree}{Doktor-Ingenieur (Dr.-Ing.)\xspace}
\newcommand{\myName}{Andr\'e Miede\xspace}
\newcommand{\myProf}{Put name here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myOtherProf}{Put name here\xspace}
\newcommand{\mySupervisor}{Put name here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myFaculty}{Put data here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myDepartment}{Put data here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myUni}{Put data here\xspace}
\newcommand{\myLocation}{Darmstadt\xspace}
\newcommand{\myTime}{August 2012\xspace}
\newcommand{\myVersion}{version 4.1\xspace}

% ********************************************************************
% Setup, finetuning, and useful commands
% ********************************************************************
\newcounter{dummy} % necessary for correct hyperlinks (to index, bib, etc.)
\newlength{\abcd} % for ab..z string length calculation
\providecommand{\mLyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}
\newcommand{\ie}{i.\,e.}
\newcommand{\Ie}{I.\,e.}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.\,g.}
\newcommand{\Eg}{E.\,g.} 
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 3. Loading some handy packages
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ******************************************************************** 
% Packages with options that might require adjustments
% ******************************************************************** 
\PassOptionsToPackage{latin9}{inputenc}    % latin9 (ISO-8859-9) = latin1+"Euro sign"
 \usepackage{inputenc}                

%\PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman,american}{babel}   % change this to your language(s)
% Spanish languages need extra options in order to work with this template
%\PassOptionsToPackage{spanish,es-lcroman}{babel}
 \usepackage{babel}                    

%% COMMENTED TO TEST BIBLIO
%\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers}{natbib}
% \usepackage{natbib}                

\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}        % math environments and more by the AMS 
 \usepackage{amsmath}

% ******************************************************************** 
% General useful packages
% ******************************************************************** 
\PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics
    \usepackage{fontenc}     
\usepackage{textcomp} % fix warning with missing font shapes
\usepackage{scrhack} % fix warnings when using KOMA with listings package          
\usepackage{xspace} % to get the spacing after macros right  
\usepackage{mparhack} % get marginpar right
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % fixes some LaTeX stuff 
\PassOptionsToPackage{printonlyused,smaller}{acronym}
    \usepackage{acronym} % nice macros for handling all acronyms in the thesis
%\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textssc{#1}} % for MinionPro
\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{#1}\hfill} % fix the list of acronyms
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 4. Setup floats: tables, (sub)figures, and captions
% ****************************************************************************************************
\usepackage{tabularx} % better tables
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} % increase table row height
\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myfloatalign}{\centering} % to be used with each float for alignment
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=hang,font=small}
\usepackage{subfig}  
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 5. Setup code listings
% ****************************************************************************************************
\usepackage{listings} 
%\lstset{emph={trueIndex,root},emphstyle=\color{BlueViolet}}%\underbar} % for special keywords
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,%C++,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},%\bfseries,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    %identifierstyle=\color{NavyBlue},
    commentstyle=\color{Green}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    numbers=none,%left,%
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,%\tiny
    stepnumber=5,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=single,
    belowcaptionskip=.75\baselineskip
    %frame=L
} 
% ****************************************************************************************************               


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 6. PDFLaTeX, hyperreferences and citation backreferences
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Using PDFLaTeX
% ********************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}
    \usepackage{hyperref}  % backref linktocpage pagebackref
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1 
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex}{graphicx}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 

% ********************************************************************
% Setup the style of the backrefs from the bibliography
% (translate the options to any language you use)
% ********************************************************************
\newcommand{\backrefnotcitedstring}{\relax}%(Not cited.)
\newcommand{\backrefcitedsinglestring}[1]{(Cited on page~#1.)}
\newcommand{\backrefcitedmultistring}[1]{(Cited on pages~#1.)}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{enable-backrefs}}%
{%
        \PassOptionsToPackage{hyperpageref}{backref}
        \usepackage{backref} % to be loaded after hyperref package 
           \renewcommand{\backreftwosep}{ and~} % separate 2 pages
           \renewcommand{\backreflastsep}{, and~} % separate last of longer list
           \renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}  % disable standard
           \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{% detailed backref
              \ifcase #1 %
                 \backrefnotcitedstring%
              \or%
                 \backrefcitedsinglestring{#2}%
              \else%
                 \backrefcitedmultistring{#2}%
              \fi}%
}{\relax}    

% ********************************************************************
% Hyperreferences
% ********************************************************************
\hypersetup{%
    %draft,    % = no hyperlinking at all (useful in b/w printouts)
    colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,%
    % uncomment the following line if you want to have black links (e.g., for printing)
    %colorlinks=false, linktocpage=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,% 
    breaklinks=true, pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,%
    plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,%
    hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O,%nesting=true,%frenchlinks,%
    urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=webgreen, %pagecolor=RoyalBlue,%
    %urlcolor=Black, linkcolor=Black, citecolor=Black, %pagecolor=Black,%
    pdftitle={\myTitle},%
    pdfauthor={\textcopyright\ \myName, \myUni, \myFaculty},%
    pdfsubject={},%
    pdfkeywords={},%
    pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},%
    pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref and classicthesis}%
}   

% ********************************************************************
% Setup autoreferences
% ********************************************************************
% There are some issues regarding autorefnames
% http://www.ureader.de/msg/136221647.aspx
% https://texfaq.org/FAQ-latexwords
% you have to redefine the makros for the 
% language you use, e.g., american, ngerman
% (as chosen when loading babel/AtBeginDocument)
% ********************************************************************
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}%
    {%
       \addto\extrasamerican{%
                    \renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{Figure}%
                    \renewcommand*{\tableautorefname}{Table}%
                    \renewcommand*{\partautorefname}{Part}%
                    \renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}%
                    \renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
                    \renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}%
                    \renewcommand*{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}%     
                }%
       \addto\extrasngerman{% 
                    \renewcommand*{\paragraphautorefname}{Absatz}%
                    \renewcommand*{\subparagraphautorefname}{Unterabsatz}%
                    \renewcommand*{\footnoteautorefname}{Fu\"snote}%
                    \renewcommand*{\FancyVerbLineautorefname}{Zeile}%
                    \renewcommand*{\theoremautorefname}{Theorem}%
                    \renewcommand*{\appendixautorefname}{Anhang}%
                    \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}{Gleichung}%        
                    \renewcommand*{\itemautorefname}{Punkt}%
                }%    
            % Fix to getting autorefs for subfigures right (thanks to Belinda Vogt for changing the definition)
            \providecommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}%              
    }{\relax}
\makeatother

%% ADDED TO TEST BIBLIO
\usepackage[apaciteclassic, notocbib, nodoi, nosectionbib]{apacite}  
\usepackage{bibtopic}


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 7. Last calls before the bar closes
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Development Stuff
% ********************************************************************
\listfiles
%\PassOptionsToPackage{l2tabu,orthodox,abort}{nag}
%    \usepackage{nag}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{warning, all}{onlyamsmath}
%    \usepackage{onlyamsmath}

% ********************************************************************
% Last, but not least...
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage{classicthesis} 
% ****************************************************************************************************
```

Thanks

Comment: You may avoid further problems in the long term by switching to biblatex. It's more flexible and easier to customise. You can insert multiple bibliographies by filtering on keywords. E.g. `\printbibliography[keyword=BurnoutAppendixBib, title={\BurnoutAppendixBib}]`

Comment: I've been playing around with biblatex together with biblatex-apa. It would be a good solution, the best. But I had everything set up with bibtex and apacite. I mean, my document is in Spanish and there are small but important details (which I managed to handle in bibtex) as, for example, no ampersands but "y" and no string nodate but "sin fecha". Loading biblatex with the localisation makes it good inside the text, but \printbibliography still uses & and nodate. To handle the nodate issue, I've added the string in the spanish .lbx, but with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: If you're close, perhaps the course is to persevere by asking for fixes for you specific difficulties with biblatex. Most changes/fixes to bibliographies using biblatex can be done in the document preamble, without having to edit other files.

Comment: I'm going to give a try to biblatex @penguinpreferred. Just posted the question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206753/biblatex-biblatex-apa-style-customization-nodate-bibstring-and-ampersand)